# Ajax Load data from remote file with specific ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am stuck In an issue. Need some help from great people like you.
I have created a small like system here.

I have a HTML file having Some Data with Different IDs.
Here you can see my `remote.html` File codes.

```
<span id="14">314</span>
<span id="15">214</span>
<span id="16">19</span>
<span id="17">124</span>
<span id="18">114</span>
```

Now I have one File `index.php`
In which I have a `<span id="output"></span>`
I want to get the Data from `Remote.HTML` With Different `ID`

For Example. `<span id="15">214</span>` will show on `Index.php` file like `<span id="output">214</span>` and so on for all `IDs` on `Remote.html`

Here is Ajax Code i am using

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update_record.php',

    success: function(data) {
                    data=$(data).find('#15');
        $('#output').html(data);

     }
    });
```

But it is not showing me anything there.

Please help me

Comment: What is the error you got?  To display error ajax in jQuery use `error: function(data){ alert('error'); }`

Comment: @isuru I am very weak in Ajax. Let me put this code to see error

Comment: @isuru When I add your Code, It shows Nothing. 
And It is not showing the Data from remote file. If you can tell me some ajax codes more better than mine, Please Tell me.

Comment: Try to see which error is being returned in your console by doing the following: error: function(e){ console.log(e); console.log(e.responseText); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
  function data(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update_record.php',

            success: function(data) { 
                var fval = $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#15")           
                $('#output').html(fval);

             }
            });
       setTimeout(function(){data();},5000);
    }
data();
```

Comment: I did, It shown the results. But all in #output I have products there. 
I meant to say. 
i am filtering it with Product ids. 
so <span id="15">214</span> will show on the #output15 where Product id is 15
i hope now you can understand sir

Comment: It should show the data only od ID 15 if we write update_record.php#15 Why it is showing all.

Comment: WOW. Thanks. It worked. But, One thing not working. It loads data only by reloading the page, Please can you help me to make it load data automatically? without refreshing page? Please

Comment: <script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'update_record.php',

    success: function(data) { 
        var fval = $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#<?php echo $pro_id ;?>")           
        $('#output<?php echo $pro_id ;?>').html(fval);

     }
    });
</script>

Comment: Can we just ad a time interval? to refresh it?

Comment: it will not refresh the page it simply updates the out put after every 5 secs

Comment: Yes I know dear but it is not doing updates after even 5 minutes. I am trying it again and again

Comment: You are Awesome. It really Worked. Thank you So much For great help